# Invalid Path error while inserting job from google cloud storage to google bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to insert a job through HTTP Post request, but i am getting Invalid path error.

My request body is as follows:

```
{
"configuration": {
"load": {
"sourceUris": [
"gs://onianalytics/PersData.csv"
],
"schema": {
"fields": [
{
"name": "Name",
"type": "STRING"
},
{
"name": "Age",
"type": "INTEGER"
}
]
},
"destinationTable": {
"datasetId": "Test_Dataset",
"projectId": "lithe-anvil-404",
"tableId": "tb_test_Pers"
}
}
},
"jobReference": {
"jobId": "10",
"projectId": "lithe-anvil-404"
}
}
```

For the sourceuri parameter, I am passing "gs://onianalytics/PersData.csv", where onianalytics is my bucket name and PersData.csv is my csv file (from which I want to upload data into google bigquery).

I am getting below response:

```
"status": {
"state": "DONE",
"errorResult": {
"reason": "invalid",
"message": "Invalid path: gs://onianalytics/PersData.csv"
},
"errors": [
{
"reason": "invalid",
"message": "Invalid path: gs://onianalytics/PersData.csv"
}
]
},
"statistics": {
"creationTime": "1387276603674",
"startTime": "1387276603751",
"endTime": "1387276603751"
}
}
```

My bucket is under the same projectid which has the BigQuery service activated. Also, I have Google Cloud Storage enabled under APIs and Auth. Following scopes are added while authenticating:

googleapis.com/auth/bigquery, googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform, googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.full_control,googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only,googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_write

I am inserting this job by "Try it!" link which is available on       developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs/insert.

In fact I am able to create buckets and objects in goggle cloud storage through APIs. But when i try to insert job from the uploaded object (which is a csv file), i got "Invalid Path" error. Can anyone please help me to identify why this error is occurring?

Comment: I am seeing the existence of your 'onianalytics' bucket which is using the [default permissions](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/lists#defaultbuckets). First ensure that your 'PersData.csv' does exists within you [bucket](https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser/onianalytics/). Then attempt to use the BigQuery Console logged in with any User account listed in your project's [IAM](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/iam/) to perform the load job by following our [guide](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage).

Answer (score 0):

The error I get when trying the code above is "Not found: URI gs://onianalytics/PersData.csv".

I'm wondering if instead of /onianalytics/ you had a different path with invalid characters?